# How to format date in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to format the date as `ddmmyyyy`. I am using SQL Server 2016 and I have found the following line that seemed to do the job but it doesn't.

Here is the code I used

```
DECLARE @ChangedDate as date

SET @ChangedDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
SET @ChangedDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @ChangedDate, 103), '-','')
```

The result when saving the document remains "2015-05-02" instead of what I want "02052015"

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *whats wrong here?*

It is caused by implicit conversion:

```
DECLARE @ChangedDate as date                 -- date NULL
SET @ChangedDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())  -- date, initialization
SET @ChangedDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @ChangedDate, 103), '-','')
--                 string converted to date
```

If you want to treat it as string do not assign to `date` variable.

```
DECLARE @ChangedDate as date  = GETDATE()
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @ChangedDate, 103), '/','');
-- 02052016
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/QEYI19625)**</kbd>

---

You could declare and assign variable at once:

```
DECLARE @ChangedDate as date  = GETDATE();
DECLARE @ChangedDate2 VARCHAR(8)=REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @ChangedDate,103),'/','');

SELECT @ChangedDate2;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/JPLXN86872)**</kbd>

---

The correct way is to return it as date and format in application layer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`FORMAT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
Select Format(GetDate(), 'ddMMyyyy')
```

Output:

> 02052016

(Note: `mm` is for `minutes`, whilst `MM` is for `months`)